# C# запуск процесса после завершения другого процесса

Tags: c#, процесс, multiprocessing

Один файл запускает 2 процесса одновременно. Оба процесса открывают один и тот же файл (первый пишет в файл, второй читает из файла).

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы сначала начинал работать 1й процесс , писал в файл, потом начинал работать 2й процесс и читал из файла? 
Важно, чтобы они запускались одновременно, 2й процесс должен дожидаться конца 1го процесса и только после этого запускаться.

Находил информацию про именованные мьютексы, однако минус в том, что первым начать работу может любой из процессов.

```
public static void  start1()
{
    Process mYproces = new Process();
    mYproces.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\mark\source\repos\file1\file1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\file1.exe";
    mYproces.Start();
    mYproces.WaitForExit();

}

public static void start2()
{
    Process mYproces = new Process();
    mYproces.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\mark\source\repos\file2\file2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\file2.exe";
    mYproces.Start();
    mYproces.WaitForExit();
    //mYproces.Kill();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var thread1 = new Thread(() => start1());
    var thread2 = new Thread(() => start2());
    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();
    thread1.Join();
    thread2.Join();
}
```

Первый exe файл

```
public static void d1() {
    Console.WriteLine("d1 start");
    StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\mark\Downloads\MYTXT.txt", true);
    f.WriteLine("Строка d1");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    f.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("d1 end");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    d1();
}
```

второй exe

```
public static void d2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("d2 start");
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\mark\Downloads\MYTXT.txt");
    string check = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    Console.WriteLine("d2 end");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    d2();
}
```

P.S.
Добавил именные мьютексы, однако возникает ошибка когда доходит до ReleaseMutex (Unhandled exception. System.ApplicationException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
   at System.Threading.Mutex.ReleaseMutex())

1 приложение

```
 public static void d1() {
        StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\mark\Downloads\MYTXT.txt", true);
        Console.WriteLine("d1 start");
        f.WriteLine("Строка d1");
        f.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("d1 end")
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        d1();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Mutex.OpenExisting("MYMUTEX").ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

2 приложение

```
public static void d2()
    {

        Mutex.OpenExisting("MYMUTEX").WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("d2 start");
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\mark\Downloads\MYTXT.txt");
        string check = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        Console.WriteLine("d2 end");


    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        d2();
    }
```

в основном приложение добавил только `Mutex mut = new Mutex(true, "MYMUTEX");`

Comment: Используйте `Mutex`. И судя по вашему коду, стартуют они не одновременно, а последовательно.

Comment: @aepot я пробовал использовать именованный mutex, сделав его внутри класса в главном файле, и за процессы обращаясь к нему. Но в таком случае если первый обратится к нему 2й процесс, тогда 1й процесс будет ждать конца работы 2го процесса.

Или я не правильно реализовал?

Comment: Лучше опишите не механику, а для чего это надо. Иначе похоже на XY-проблему https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy

Comment: Создайте именованный мьютекс в главном приложении. В первом приложении стартуйте не обращая на него внимания, и в первом же приложении освободите мьютекс при завершении. А во втором в самом начале просто ждите освобождения мьютекса.

Comment: И старт дочерних потоков сделайте не старт-джойн-старт-джойн, а старт-старт-джойн-джойн

Comment: @aepot именованный mutex передавать в первое приложение, через добавление ссылки на главное приложение? старт дочерних потоков исправил

Comment: Именованный мьютекс - он на то и именованный, что его можно получить по имени. :)

Comment: @aepot огромное спасибо, это то что я искал, я реализовал это, однако я не могу в 1м приложении реализовать Mutex.OpenExisting("MYMUTEX").ReleaseMutex() из-за водникающей ошибки. В ошибки пишет что вызвано из несинхронизированного блока (Unhandled exception. System.ApplicationException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.)

Никак не могу решить данную проблему

Comment: Я написал ответ, логика получилась немного другой от той, которую я предлагал выше, но получилась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.` означает что вы пытаетесь зарелизить `Mutex`, установленный в другом потоке, не синхронизированном с текущим. Другими словами, если один поток занял мьютекс, то только он его может освободить, но ждать этого освобождения можно в любом потоке.

Вот пример блокировки с одним `Mutex` и двумя одновременно страртующими процессами. Пример сделал на базе одного и того же приложения с разными аргументами запуска.

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        switch (args[0])
        {
            case "process1":
                Console.WriteLine("Process 1 started");
                Thread.Sleep(2000); // какая-то работа
                Console.WriteLine("Process 1 finished");
                break;
            case "process2":
                Mutex.OpenExisting("MyMutex").WaitOne(); // ждем, пока нас отпустят
                Console.WriteLine("Process 2 started");
                Thread.Sleep(2000); // какая-то работа
                Console.WriteLine("Process 2 finished");
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "MyMutex");
        mutex.WaitOne(); // сажаем на цепь второй процесс
        Console.WriteLine("Main process started");

        // пусть к самому себе для .NET Core 3.1, как я понял, это он у вас
        string path = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;

        Process process1 = new Process();
        process1.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "process1";
        // можно сделать так, чтобы процесс стартовал в отдельном окне
        // process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

        Process process2 = new Process();
        process2.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        process2.StartInfo.Arguments = "process2";
        // process2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

        process1.Start();
        process2.Start();
        // оба дочерних процесса запущены, все по правилам

        process1.WaitForExit();
        mutex.ReleaseMutex(); // отпускаем второй процесс
        process2.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine("Main process finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Потоки `Thread` вам здесь не нужны, совсем.

```
Main process started
Process 1 started
Process 1 finished
Process 2 started
Process 2 finished
Main process finished
```

Comment: Понял логику, огромное спасибо тебе за то что все объяснил